# SharePoint App Crossdomain Rest function rewritten as a Promise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, app, promises

I have written a successful crossdomain call using Rest which is hosted in an Menu Action App. It  returns all document item properties.  Ok now I think is the time to rewrite as a JavaScript" Promise. Could someone please take look at my code to see if I am on the write lines - allot of  the samples I have seen seem to use $.ajax() whereas I have previously used a different syntax as shown below.

```
  // define our unique namespace for our functions.
 var WSL = window.Client.WSL || {};
  WSL.Rest = WSL.Rest || {};

  WSL.Rest.Lists = function () {


// REST Style promise functions
var getItemAllFields = function () {


    var deferred = $.Deferred();


    var executor;


    $('#message').text("REST Cross domain call");   // document.getElementById("message").innerText =

    // although we're fetching data from the host web, SP.RequestExecutor gets initialized with the app web URL..
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);



    var urlItemAllFields = appweburl +
                  "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + itemurl + "')/ListItemAllFields?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";



    executor.executeAsync(
    {

        url: urlItemAllFields,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: Function.createDelegate(this, function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) { 
            //alert('Sucess');
            deferred.resove(data, errorCode,errorMessage);


        }),

        error:  Function.createDelegate(this, function (data, error, errorMessage) { deferred.reject(data, error, errorMessage); 


        }));




        return deferred.promise();



     };



return {

    getItemAllFields: getItemAllFields

 };


 }();
```

Answer (score 0):

Those samples using `$.ajax()` are the ones which are working in a single domain whereas `SP.RequestExecutor` is mainly used to perform cross domain calls. The code above is making a REST call on Host Web from an App Web and as you may be aware they are in different domains hence the need for it. Note, that if your List is in App Web itself, then you can very well use `$.ajax()` instead of `SP.RequestExecutor`

**UPDATE**

The problem is you can't make a cross-domain call with AJAX because the same-origin policy will stop the call. That's why we have the cross-domain library in the first place. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) The only way to use ajax for cross-domain calls is with JSONP (GET only), or if the target supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)." On the positive side, jQuery.ajax returns a promise, so it's nicer for calls within the same origin.

Comment: ah that makes sense. In my case I do very little in the app web so it would have to be cross domain. Thanks

Comment: You can do GET requests using `$.ajax()` for cross-domain requests as well.  You still need to use the `/_api/SP.AppContextSite` endpoint as you do with the `RequestExecutor`.

Comment: @wjervis, that make sense, it essentially boils down to using `RequestExecutor` for getting the `AppContextSite'. There is a choice in using either `$.ajax()` or `executor.executeAsync'. And this also mean not only can we do `GET`, we can make `POST` calls as well using `$.ajax()`

Comment: Ok I will try this

Comment: @NadeemYousuf, I did not know that you can make `POST` calls with `$.ajax()`.  I always got an error, but that was probably me forgetting to add the request digest and other things that `RequestExecutor` automatically handled for you.

Comment: @wjervis, we have got westerdaled doing the testing. Hoefully, he will come up with the results :-)

Comment: Hi my code compiles and runs and returns the promise. I don't see it hitting either the success or error functions . syntactically it is worse to code the that executor...Shall I start a new post with the code

Comment: Yes post a new question. It will get better attention from the users

Comment: all, I have made contact with Scott Hillier, wrt the SP.RequestExecutor version of my code which is far easier to understand than the $.ajax() call. I have published the main parts of the code to see if the syntax is ok. Should have an ans a bit later.

Comment: To quote Scott: " he problem is you can't make a cross-domain call with AJAX because the same-origin policy will stop the call. That's why we have the cross-domain library in the first place.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

The only way to use ajax for cross-domain calls is with JSONP (GET only), or if the target supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)."

On the positive side, jQuery.ajax returns a promise, so it's nicer for calls within the same origin.

Comment: @westerdaled, that is a nice information. Let me edit the answe and put this comment in it, so that it will be useful for other community users who may not go through our length discussion :-)

Comment: All working and of course not using $.ajax() .. Thanks again for Scott's code review which as the deal maker.

Comment: @westerdaled, good to hear that.